# Change color of dynamically loaded SVG

Tags: angularjs, svg

I'm inserting an SVG through AngularJS:

```
<embed embed-src="{{sportImage}}" type="image/svg+xml" class="svg sport-image" width="470" height="418" />
```

But I can't change the fill of the svg or path through CSS or JS. I'm guessing this is because the SVG is loaded after the API returns its results.

Any tips?

Comment: if you add your svg as inline svg you should be able to do anything you want with it. is there a reason not to add it as inline?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the change after the onload of the `<embed>` has occurred.

```
<embed embed-src="{{sportImage}}" type="image/svg+xml" class="svg sport-image" width="470" height="418" onload="f()" id="something" />
<script>
    function f() {
        var svg = document.getElementById('something');
        var element = svg.getSVGDocument().getElementById("an-id-in-the-embedding");
        element.setAttribute("fill", "some-colour");
    }
</script>
```